# Compile several files together?

Tags: c++, file, compilation

I have

- Data.cpp
- Data.h
- User.cpp
- User.h
- main.cpp

Main.cpp need data.cpp and user.cpp. How do I link or compile them? They all in same directory? (please be more specific, like which file to compile first.)

My system is: Mac OS X, g++ compiler in terminal.

Comment: Why not use Xcode? Or makefiles? Do not use commandline directly for compiling bigger C++ projects.

Comment: Xcode only on Mac, but i need to run it(demo) in linux :(

Comment: And, xcode gave me problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284468/android-source-code-build-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way :

```
g++ Data.cpp User.cpp main.cpp
```

More advanced way : use a makefile

Comment: @cpp_noob: That is your homework for today. You'll figure it out.

Comment: @cpp_noob Pick a makefile tutorial. For example :http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm

Comment: Thank you.. I have another homework to submit today.. I guess I postpone this homework to tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
g++ main.cpp Data.cpp User.cpp -o myexecutable
```

All source files are compiled individually, so the order is not important. After the compilation, g++ does the linking as well.

Answer (score 1):

Compile each one seperately to object files.
Then link the object files to an application.

Comment: Look at Eser's answer. Or use the linker of your choice. The GNU-Linker ld is maybe the most common.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are stating things in a wrong way:

`Main.cpp` does **not** need `user.cpp`: he just needs to have the definition of the types implemented in `user.cpp`. That's why you just need to include `user.h` in your `Main.cpp`.

Usually, every `.cpp` file turns into its own *translation* unit and give a different *object file*. These files are then assembled when the *linking* process takes place.

Basically, the steps are:

1. For every source file (`.cpp`), you generate an **object file** (compilation).
2. You assemble these object files into the resulting binary (linking).

Usually, people using a tool like `Makefile` or even better: `SConstruct` to automate these steps.

`SConstruct` is good, because it also parses the source file and build a dependency tree before compiling, to ensure that everything goes well.

Comment: Does `SConstruct` actually work?  I've tried several such systems (e.g. `Jam`), and to date, the only one that has worked is good old make, with rules to create the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be

```
g++ main.cpp Data.cpp User.cpp -o program_name
```